# When will I see my friend?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, story, music

My friend and I both sing in the choir of our local episcopal church, but our choir director is really strict. He doesn't like people talking much. At our last rehearsal, right at the end of a break, I asked my friend if she wanted to come over to my house sometime this week. But before she could answer, the director ended the break and restarted our rehearsal.

However, a minute later, my friend ripped a scrap of paper and scribbled something on it. She tucked the paper inside my hymnal, which was lying on the bench, and poked me in the side.

When I pulled the paper out later, I smiled. I knew exactly when I would see her next. The paper looked like this:

> WLP.756.R.7.1 427.2.10.3 256.2.3.2 494.4.3.1 GC.689.4.2.4 8.1.1.1

When will I see my friend?

(The story is fictional, but the details matter. I made this up myself, so I’m not sure if it’s too hard though.)

Edit, spoilered just in case:

> The GC string of numbers should probably have 708 instead of 689 because in the physical book it was 689, but the second edition online calls it 708 instead.

Hint:

> She scribbled 1982 on the bottom of the note.

Bigger hint:

> We gather comprehensive-ly in 1982 to give wonder, love, and praise.

Comment: this is something about the Wonder Love and Praise supplement of the hymnal 1982, im pretty sure `WLP.756` here means the #756th song of WLP(wonder love praise) which is `Lead me, guide me, along the way`, currently i have no idea what the remaining codes meant xD

Answer (score 1):

> https://www.churchpublishing.org/products/wonderloveandpraise
>  Wonder, Love, and Praise
>  A Supplement to The Hymnal 1982, Pew Edition

> I do not have this book with me, hence I can not proceed to Decrypt the code, but I guess it is Pointing to Page or Hymn, verse, line, word, and letter Positions.

> Starting with one Possibility:
>  WLP == Wonder, Love, and Praise
>  WLP.756.R.7.1 == WLP, HYMN 756 "Lead Me, Guide Me", R=refrain, WORD 7, LETTER 1 == W
>  427.2.10.3 == WLP, HYMN 427 "When morning gilds the skies", verse 2, WORD 10, LETTER 3 == g
>      256.2.3.2 == WLP, HYMN 256 "A light from heaven shone around", verse 2, WORD 3, LETTER 2 == h
>      494.4.3.1 == WLP, HYMN 494 "Crown him with many crowns", verse 4, WORD 3, LETTER 1 == t
>  GC = gather comprehensive ? SOme other Book or same book ? Let me continue with same book
>  GC.689.4.2.4  ==
>      8.1.1.1 ==

Comment: the book is available on the internet tho, https://www.riteseries.org/song/wlp/

Comment: Oh, thanks @Anonymouse , I will use that Online Version ! I hope the Puzzle is not using Page numbers of the Print Version !

Comment: np, ive checked several online version and fortunately the page numbers are all the same

Comment: Well, unfortunately, the Online Version mentioned by @Anonymouse is not free; It requires Payment to access.

Comment: oh damn, yeah its unfortunate that this puzzle can only be solved by the ones that already bought the book

Comment: You’ve got that bit right. If you look at the hymn anywhere else you should be able to get the lyrics — you’re looking for a word for each set of numbers; you can get it from any printing of the hymn that includes sheet music.

Comment: @anonymouse You can use hymnary.org to find the hymn, then google the sheet music. I just checked and it’ll work to solve the puzzle.

Comment: It’s not letters. You’re looking for whole words — and actually only the ones with a prefix come from that book. But great job so far!!